# C++ An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Tags: c++

So, I am trying to write a program that will eventually create a 2D array that will contain the location of mathematical operators in a user input string. so, for example, if the user put in 2+5-3, I want my array to be something like {{+,1}{-,3}}. I intended to just use an integer array and a known translation from +,-,/,*,^ to 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. however I keep getting an exception thrown when I try to test it saying "string subscript out of range" and then my IDE puts up an error code on my if statement that reads "An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal". Any Ideas where I've messed up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
equationstart:
    string eq;
    int posOp[50][2];
    int i;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3;

    getline(cin, eq);
    for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
        if (eq[i] == '+') {
            posOp[i2][0] = 1;
            posOp[i2][1] = i;
            i2++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
        for (i3 = 0; i3 <= 1; i3++) {
            cout << posOp[i][i3];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    goto equationstart;

}
```

right now all I want it to do is fill the array then display the acquired array to the screen so I can see that it is working.

Comment: Maybe there were not 50 characters typed on the line that you input. You assume eq is at least 50 characters here: `if (eq[i] == '+') {`

Comment: don't recommend gotos, use while loop instead, gotos for breaking out of heavily nested loops, avoid goto in general

Comment: that fixed it, thank you, sorry for being dumb

Comment: in the end function it's going to it is a call to a different function, I only used the goto for testing purposes so the program would just automatically repeat the entire program

Comment: ***if the user put in 2+5-3, I want my array to be something like {{+,1}{-,3}}.*** I don't see the code doing that to the array. Also the array is an array of integers.

Comment: the if (eq[i] == '+') finds every instance of a plus, and writes 1 to the first position of the array to indicate a plus sign, and then it puts the index where it was found into the second position in the array. then I just have to copy paste the same code and run if (eq[i] == '-') and insert a 2 instead of a 1, etc.

Comment: I am not sure the 2D array is the best approach however  if you continue with it you will need to initialize the array. `int posOp[50][2];` declares but does not initialize any elements of the array.

Comment: I planned on eventually throwing in a loop that sets all values in the array to 0, but was at the point of just testing the one thing to see if it worked before adding the rest and cleaning it up.

Answer (score 2):

a) please don't use C arrays `posOp[50][2]`. Use std::vector instead. It comes with range checking, if you use posOp.at(idx). std::vector is one of the most basic and most important C++ features.

b) As @drescherjm pointed out in the comments above, `eq[i]` will trigger an exception (fortunately), when eq.size() is less than 50. Your loop runs from 0 to 49, which is fine for `posOp`, but eq may be shorter. You are accessing eq beyond it's end.

Comment: yep,changing it to 
```
strlen = eq.length();
 if (strlen >= 49) {
  cout << "Equation too long" << endl;
  goto equationstart;
 }
 for (i = 0; i <= strlen; i++)
```
fixed it

Comment: Glad to hear that you fixed it.     BTW, consider avoiding length assumptions and fixed length vectors. You assume that 50 will be long enough for all cases. These kinds of assumptions are one of the leading causes for the security problems that plague the IT-World. Malware writers will search for assumptions such as these and exploit them.    Use std::vector and all the other good containers from std and write your code so that it works with any length or at the bare minimum check _every_ assumption in your code and print an error, if its wrong.

Comment: I did end up writing in an error if the string length is over 50, so even if the string where entirely made of operators, it couldn't overrun the posOp matrix. I will look into vectors, I am really just starting to learn as a hobby. there is 0 chance of this program ever leaving my computer lol